# Simple HTTP Request vs Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, security, servlets

One desktop application needs to get some services from server.
For example sending some parameters and receiving some result.

Imagine implementing a solution by Java Servlets, in a way that the app sends the parameters to the servlet (POST) and receives the result in XML.

Does this approach have any security issue in compare with web-services (Soap / Restful) ?

Thanks and sorry if the question is a bit general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your solution has suitable authentication (username/password) and takes place over SSL, it's no less secure than Web Services/SOAP. And indeed you might find it a simpler solution to implement.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. But personally I would still go over REST, mainly because it would be easier to maintain and update if needed. Also probably easier to test and implement.

Answer (score 2):

The security issue is the same for both solutions because it's http but I won't do the post thing because it's not structured properly, meaning it's client dependent and not using a standard. If you don't like XML, you can try JSON.